Colonizing a frozen Waterworld
So in my fictional scenario a civilization has to leave their home planet. Having no possibility to travel close to light speed, their best bet is the neighboring system which includes an ice world with a big frozen Ocean. Kind of like Ganymede or Titan in our System.
Some more info about the Civilization:

Their technological Abilities are maybe 20 years ahead of ours.
Number of People arriving at the world: 1000

Some more info about the system which is to be made habitable:

The Star is sun-like in Mass, Luminosity and Radiation levels.
Semi Major Axis of the Planet is 3 AU
The Planet has 1 Earth Mass
It has a Moon of 1 Lunar Mass
Moon and Planet compose a double system similar to ours, where the moon stabilizes its host axis.

According to my research in sun like systems there is always an abundance of water and other lighter elements, the further you go from the star. For example Ganymede has so much water, that its sub-glacial ocean is solid at the ground, according to Wikipedia.
Also a red dwarf system is out of question because these tend to have nasty radiation outbreaks which would blow an atmosphere away.
So my Question is: How would the terraforming process look like?

Humans have never even been to another planet. The notion that we could reach planets in other solar systems and successfully terraform and colonize them with just another 20 years of technological development seems... far-fetched.

The terraforming process would look like, awesome, like. It would look like an awe-inspiring epic struggle between the iron will of Man and frozen stubborness of Nature. Countless generations of poets would glorify the unrelenting tenacity of the Terraforming Heroes who transceded the mortal nature of man to persist in their multimillennary effort to carve a home for mankind on the icy new world. The image of the visionaries who first started the process would shine like a shiny beacon of light through the eons of unforgiving work. It would look like nothing else in human history. Etc. etc.

Question subject line is about colonization yet body question is about terraforming, two different things Ideally they would be similar . What is the end goal of the terraforming? What resources exist to accomplish any terraforming?

Oh I'm sure it will be epic. Well maybe we can increase the time span to 60 Years instead of 20?

@NuclearHoagie Reach them in 20 years, no. But the technology to travel to other stars existed back in the 1950s, with Project Orion; according to Freeman Dyson's papers, it'd've "only" cost something equal to an entire year's worth of US GDP to implement. Turns out nukes have a rather high specific impulse.

@GaultDrakkor Resources include Specimens of Plant Seedlings, Farm Animals, Greenhouse Gas generators (A.k.a fossil industries),
Since there is a lot of ice, they do not need to bring extra water.
I'm not sure about the nitrogen though, which is used to have an ecosystem like we have here...
The Goal would be having a wide variety of ecosystems similar like we have it on earth, a breathable atmosphere, and if possible continents and oceans.

Ideally they would alter the planets atmosphere and use that as a base for generating a biosphere later. The biosphere enables them to build a larger economy that allows for a bigger population in the future. The Atmosphere is similar to the one on saturn's moon titan

The reason I was asking about resources is 1000 people is low.  Low in terms of people to get things done. Low in terms of genetic diversity as well.  Which means lots of automation. you mention greenhouse gfass generators, Current tech would require hundreds of thousands to millions of people for building additional units extracting and refining fuel, operating. maintaining the units plus supporting infrastructure. Better automation can cut down the number of people but it requires substantial amounts of infrastructure.

Sure, we can increase the amount of people to 10000 maybe? Or higher. But i think we will need generation ships for that. Which is absolutely fine with me

Frame Challenge: Your story line is about faced.
At the moment? Your traveling to the planet to colonize it and then terraforming it. In reality? You would need to Terraform the planet first and then travel there to colonize it.
The first problem? Radically terraforming a planet would take generations to complete even using (realistic) advanced technology. So in this instance your science and engineering teams would have to leave for your 'ice world' long before the bulk of your colonists do (unless your just planning to use frozen eggs or sperm and ova as your colonists).
Your second problem? Terraforming your ice world isn't really going to give you a planet suitable for large scale human habitation because what you'll end up with is a 'ocean' world. Sure you can colonize that world ocean with oxygen producing algae, then build up an oceanic ecosystem from there all the way from plankton up through to whales if you want. But that's not going to give you any land masses for humans to colonize. And if your population is restricted to living on artificial, man made floating 'islands' as an alternative? You may as well not bother and just build large  rotating space habitats instead because that will be much quicker and less resource intensive than the effort required to Terraform the planet and build the floating habitats.
And if you do decide to go down that path instead? Well then you probably don't even have to leave the solar system to begin with. Just build them at home!
EDIT: That last bit changes though if you you alter your story to give the planet changes ice free/above sea level land masses as well as a frozen ocean.

Yes i made this post regarding ice worlds with less water.
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/257743/sun-like-star-system-with-less-water-close-to-the-frost-line

Alas my goal is to have at least one terraformed world with continents, ecosystems and habitats.

It is OK to rephrase the question and ask it again with continents specifically included the 2nd time you know.

Paraphrasing:  If Earth were moved to the outer main asteroid belt (and the belt and Jupiter removed), and humans came upon it, what could we do?

Land, dig graves, occupy graves.  Unless you are incredibly well prepared, you have neither the population nor infrastructure to survive.
Stay in orbit.  I have heard that the atmosphere absorbs about 90% of solar radiation.  This means that, in your planet's orbit, the light levels are approximately correct.  There, you might be able to setup habitats and grow food.  After a few centuries, and developing a population in the tens or hundreds of millions, there might be some radicals who want to try terraforming the planet.  (And this, despite the fact that the ancestors left clear instructions to do so!)

Until some technology like a beanstalk is available, it would be axiomatic that anyone who lands on the planet will die there.  Not that it is necessarily fatal, but that it is too hard to make a launch vehicle on the planet, or to make a launch vehicle that can land and then launch.  A small colony that receives regular food and fuel drops might be established early on.  This would serve as a scientific research outpost, and perform some experiments.
The real challenge to terraforming in this case is warming the planet.  This planet will make an ice age look toasty!
Instead of terraforming the ice-world, you might consider ice-world-forming the Terrans.  (suggested reading: Spacehounds of IPC by E.E. "Doc" Smith, where a few chapters focus on a visit to one of Saturn's moons)

Thank you for the answer. If you say "well prepared", what capacities and resources would that translate into?
Maybe 1000x the population to start with and infinite energy supply, for example through nuclear fusion power plants?
Obviously we have the ability to produce immense amounts of greenhouse gasses.
I'm sure we can melt the ice somehow...

Also i'm not sure about the term "Beanstalk", haven't heard of it yet. Maybe you mean something like thist?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator?

@Ben "beanstalk" has been used to describe the concept of a space elevator long, long before any other term was in use - at least 40 years that I can remember.

Thats ok, im actually into this concept.

Well prepared:  First off, you need food.setting up a food infrastructure on-planet will require a lot.  Pre-industrial,  it would have been ~99% of population.  Currently, maybe ~1%.  But:  that doesn't count the manufacturing processes to build the tractor, or to fuel the tractor, or to transport the food, etc etc etc.  If you are going to land at once on ice-world, you won't be able to do most of these things, and the ice will make you unable to build most of them.  So unless you land with perhaps 100 years of supplies for a growing population, you are probably in trouble.

It depends how cold your water world is.
If the atmosphere has snowed out, its basically a vacum moon on the surface.
So where are the problems?
First, you do not really want to teraform. You can live pretty cozy in basically a giant iglu/mineshafts in ice. You have water, with water you have oxygen and hydrogen, the problem is everything else.
Carbon(dioxid):
You will have to mine the surface layer for gas - or extract it from the ice.
Metalls:
This is where the problem starts, you have only what you brought along. Again there might be small amounts dissolved in the ice, but its not enough for anything. Once you take your ship apart you would never again get into orbit. If you have a asteroid belt, you might be able to make and drop resource ingots down to your community.
Stone/Substrate:
Farming has come a long way, but hydroponics is work intensive. And you can not create greenhouse farms near the surface, due to a lack of substrate. Again, you would need to mine it from the ice ocean floor (60 km straight down in ice) or from the asteroid belt.
All this requires industry, which produces heat and gets its power from somewhere? And at some point, the question arises- what is the benefit from living on this planet? You could have the same ice in a asteroid belt - built the same environment in a belt, create o Neil Cylinders and life happily ever after. Just because its a ball of things, it is not necessary a good idea to land and life on it.

Okay according to my simulation my ice world is like -85 degree Celcius.
If were choosing an ice world with less ice and more silicates on the surface, the terraforming effort could yield a planet with oceans, continents aka substrate, and an atmosphere, which is already there, but needs to be maintained.
Energy we can get from Geothermal heat, nuclear power plants and/or fossil fuels we brought.

Also i made this post regarding ice worlds to colonize that not only have ice on the surface.
https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/257743/sun-like-star-system-with-less-water-close-to-the-frost-line

Yes you are right. There are people in my scenario that think exactly like you and settled on these O'Neil cylinders and are happy with it. But some wanted to have an actual world with oceans and continents.
They are afraid that this artificial construction would break and then they are exposed to space. Remember: There are people who think that earth is flat. How would they maintain this construction if they experience technological regression?

Be a tube worm. Live around volcanic vents.
Without some unknown huge source of heat, you are not going to warm up the planet much.
At 3x the Earth's radius you will receive 1/9th of the heating. The planet also radiates heat back into space. The equilibrium, between the two pretty much determines the average temperature at the surface: adding an atmosphere may move the balance a bit, but not much. The planet may have a hot core from radioactive decay, or from tidal heating if it orbits a larger planet. You can use this heat to create out of equilibrium hot spots to live in.
Ganymede and Titan have stuff other than water at the surface. Ganymede has little atmosphere. Titan has a thick atmosphere. Something like Europa might present a real challenge as it has deep water, so what you find at the surface will be pretty pure ice and not much use for life or building a better spacecraft. However, meteorites do come down, and are easy to spot on ice, so you can get some meteoric iron. But if you are somewhere where heat and minerals rise, then you have a much better chance of being self-sustaining.
PS:
You don't have to be a tube-worm. The dwellings around the vents could be city-sized. You could have large does that looked like outdoors. Your waste heat can be used to generate electricity more efficiently than you can on Earth because it is cold outside. You may not be able to support tens of billions, but it is not clear we can do that on Earth either in a sustainable way. Settle for tens of millions and you should be fine.

Thank you for the answer. Yeah the planets in my Scenario have a very hot and active core, layers comparable to our earth.

If i would want to increase the heat the planet receives from a star, i could choose a bigger, brighter star. That's Okay, but we will need to find a way to shield ourselves from the increased UV-Radiation a type F star has. (white main sequence stars)
